# Facebook http / Https error

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm attempting to put a facebook like button on my website using facebook's html5 like button. When liking the page it crashes and gives me this console error message:

Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Read on Same Origin Policy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy - Basically both endpoints need to have matching protocols. Either change the iframe source to match the request endpoint or vice-versa

Comment: The iframe has the origin of http wich is the correct origin for the website as it does not have https.

Comment: Could you post your HTML and some context maybe

Comment: the html would be whats generated from developers.facebook.com